# GNUCash — Adding Namespace Item to Price Editor

Tags: gnucash

In the Price Editor in GNUCash you have to choose from a list of seven items: Currencies, All non-currencies, AMEX, EUREX, FUND, NASDAQ and NYSE.

Is there any way of adding an item to this list?

I haven't been able to find anything the GNUCash Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

When adding a new security (Tools > Security Editor > Add), there is a dropdown to select the namespace labelled "Type".  This field is also an input box, and the value for a new namespace can be typed into the field while creating the new security.  When the security is added, a new namespace will appear on the list of "Types" in the future.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to figure this out and was beginning to think it couldn't be done.   Thank You!